# Java agent library failed to init: instrument

Tags: java, jvm, javaagents

I'm working on an open-source project called ["Cloudnet-v3"](https://github.com/CloudNetService/CloudNet-v3). I am using a symlink /data on my local machine to the data-point in my IntelliJProjects-Folder.

I got the following startup command:

```sh
[java, -XX:+UseG1GC, -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=50, -XX:-UseAdaptiveSizePolicy, -XX:CompileThreshold=100, -XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions, -XX:+UseCompressedOops, -Dcom.mojang.eula.agree=true, -Djline.terminal=jline.UnsupportedTerminal, -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8, -Dio.netty.noPreferDirect=true, -Dclient.encoding.override=UTF-8, -Dio.netty.maxDirectMemory=0, -Dio.netty.leakDetectionLevel=DISABLED, -Dio.netty.recycler.maxCapacity=0, -Dio.netty.recycler.maxCapacity.default=0, -DIReallyKnowWhatIAmDoingISwear=true, -Dcloudnet.wrapper.receivedMessages.language=english, -Xmx372M, -javaagent: "/data/temp/caches/wrapper.jar", -cp, "/data/launcher/libs/io/kubernetes/client-java/4.0.0/client-java-4.0.0.jar:/data/launcher/libs/io/netty/netty-codec-http/4.1.36.Final/netty-codec-http-4.1.36.Final.jar:/data/launcher/libs/io/netty/netty-handler/4.1.36.Final/netty-handler-4.1.36.Final.jar:/data/launcher/libs/io/netty/netty-transport-native-epoll/4.1.36.Final/netty-transport-native-epoll-4.1.36.Final-linux-x86_64.jar:/data/launcher/libs/io/netty/netty-transport-native-kqueue/4.1.36.Final/netty-transport-native-kqueue-4.1.36.Final-osx-x86_64.jar:/data/launcher/libs/io/kubernetes/client-java-api/4.0.0/client-java-api-4.0.0.jar:/data/launcher/libs/io/kubernetes/client-java-proto/4.0.0/client-java-proto-4.0.0.jar:/data/launcher/libs/org/yaml/snakeyaml/1.19/snakeyaml-1.19.jar:/data/launcher/libs/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.11/commons-codec-1.11.jar:/data/launcher/libs/org/apache/commons/commons-compress/1.18/commons-compress-1.18.jar:/data/launcher/libs/org/apache/commons/commons-lang3/3.7/commons-lang3-3.7.jar:/data/launcher/libs/com/squareup/okhttp/okhttp-ws/2.7.5/okhttp-ws-2.7.5.jar:/data/launcher/libs/com/google/guava/guava/25.1-jre/guava-25.1-jre.jar:/data/launcher/libs/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.25/slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar:/data/launcher/libs/org/bouncycastle/bcprov-ext-jdk15on/1.59/bcprov-ext-jdk15on-1.59.jar:/data/launcher/libs/org/bouncycastle/bcpkix-jdk15on/1.59/bcpkix-jdk15on-1.59.jar:/data/launcher/libs/com/google/protobuf/protobuf-java/3.4.0/protobuf-java-3.4.0.jar:/data/launcher/libs/com/google/code/gson/gson/2.8.2/gson-2.8.2.jar:/data/launcher/libs/io/netty/netty-codec/4.1.36.Final/netty-codec-4.1.36.Final.jar:/data/launcher/libs/io/netty/netty-transport-native-unix-common/4.1.36.Final/netty-transport-native-unix-common-4.1.36.Final.jar:/data/launcher/libs/io/netty/netty-transport/4.1.36.Final/netty-transport-4.1.36.Final.jar:/data/launcher/libs/io/netty/netty-buffer/4.1.36.Final/netty-buffer-4.1.36.Final.jar:/data/launcher/libs/io/netty/netty-resolver/4.1.36.Final/netty-resolver-4.1.36.Final.jar:/data/launcher/libs/io/netty/netty-common/4.1.36.Final/netty-common-4.1.36.Final.jar:/data/launcher/libs/io/sundr/builder-annotations/0.9.2/builder-annotations-0.9.2.jar:/data/launcher/libs/io/swagger/swagger-annotations/1.5.12/swagger-annotations-1.5.12.jar:/data/launcher/libs/com/squareup/okhttp/logging-interceptor/2.7.5/logging-interceptor-2.7.5.jar:/data/launcher/libs/com/squareup/okhttp/okhttp/2.7.5/okhttp-2.7.5.jar:/data/launcher/libs/joda-time/joda-time/2.9.3/joda-time-2.9.3.jar:/data/launcher/libs/org/joda/joda-convert/1.2/joda-convert-1.2.jar:/data/launcher/libs/com/google/code/findbugs/jsr305/3.0.2/jsr305-3.0.2.jar:/data/launcher/libs/org/checkerframework/checker-qual/2.0.0/checker-qual-2.0.0.jar:/data/launcher/libs/com/google/errorprone/error_prone_annotations/2.1.3/error_prone_annotations-2.1.3.jar:/data/launcher/libs/com/google/j2objc/j2objc-annotations/1.1/j2objc-annotations-1.1.jar:/data/launcher/libs/org/codehaus/mojo/animal-sniffer-annotations/1.14/animal-sniffer-annotations-1.14.jar:/data/launcher/libs/org/bouncycastle/bcprov-jdk15on/1.59/bcprov-jdk15on-1.59.jar:/data/launcher/libs/io/sundr/sundr-core/0.9.2/sundr-core-0.9.2.jar:/data/launcher/libs/io/sundr/sundr-codegen/0.9.2/sundr-codegen-0.9.2.jar:/data/launcher/libs/io/sundr/resourcecify-annotations/0.9.2/resourcecify-annotations-0.9.2.jar:/data/launcher/libs/com/squareup/okio/okio/1.6.0/okio-1.6.0.jar:/data/launcher/versions/3.0.0-RELEASE-e48128a/driver.jar:/data/temp/caches/wrapper.jar", de.dytanic.cloudnet.wrapper.Main, nogui]
```

And my current workdir is: `/data/temp/services/Lobby-1#4a517311-09e6-4f77-89a5-64b4bc15399a`

So whenever I am in the workdir and execute the given command, it fails with the following error: `Error opening zip file or JAR manifest missing : 
Error occurred during initialization of VM
agent library failed to init: instrument` [Full Log](https://gist.github.com/PascalKu/5c894433ec0d3d871532120183f8d19c)

Now I am wondering because it's working in the automatic-environment but there are no changes to the master-Branch Source e.g. a changed Path to /data/launcher instead of launcher (`System.getProperty("cloudnet.launcher.dir", "/data/launcher")`)[https://github.com/CloudNetService/CloudNet-v3/blob/master/cloudnet-launcher/src/main/java/de/dytanic/cloudnet/launcher/Constants.java].

A short lookup: [`ls -laR  /Users/.../Documents/IdeaProjects/cloudnet-parent/data`](https://gist.github.com/PascalKu/2c7c44bcc4462770f4cf12fe4f3739be)

Comment: Can you try to clean up your question so only the relevant parts are shown? You posted a wall of text, and it's hard to figure out what's relevant.

Comment: Uhm, do you have some Ideas, what do you think is relevant and what isn't? The biggest part is my command which is still buggy... But I don't really know what is bugging on it, so I posted the whole...?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`javaagent` option is misused. Correct syntax is

```
-javaagent:/data/temp/caches/wrapper.jar
```

Comment: Hey! Cool, thanks for your contribution! Seems like it has been fixed by removing the quotation marks but I also got an issue with my command. I replaced all commas by space so my -cp String was one long link pointing to nothing.